# create dictionary from a list of strings, where each string contains a code and index

Tags: python

I have a data set that of strings where each string contains 19 unique 3 letter codes and the index where that code occurs. Most of the data is redundant (as the data set is comprised of 5 nearly identical data sets). I formatted each entry into a list. I want to create a dictionary that indicates all the indices where that code occurs. I was attempting to do this by creating a list of indices for each code at which the code occurs as the value in the dictionary. Here is what I have so far:

```
code_and_index = \
    [          "ALA    1",
               "THR    2",
               "GLN    3",
               "ALA    4",
               "ARG    5",
               "ASP    6",
               "THR    7",
               "THR  276",
               "ALA  277",
               "ILE  278",
               "GLY  279",
               "LEU  335",
               "GLY  336",
               "GLU  337",
               "GLN  338",
               "PRO  339",
               "MET  340",
               "ALA  341",
               "HIS  342",
               "ARG  343",
               "PRO  344",
               "PRO  345",
               "ALA  346",
               "THR  347",
               "PHE  348",
               "GLN  349",
               "ALA  350",
               "ASN  351",
               "LYS  352",
               "THR  353",
               "ASP  354",
               "ASP  355",
               "CYS  356",
               "SER  357",
               "ALA  358",
               "MET  359",
               "GLY  360",
               "ASN  361",
               "HIS  362",
               "CYS  363",
               "SER  364",
               "HIS  365",
               "VAL  366",
               "GLY  367",
               "GLY  368",
               "PRO  369",
               "GLN  370",
               "ASP  371",
               "LEU  372",
               "GLU  373",
               "LYS  374",
               "THR  375",
               "PRO  376",
               "ARG  377",
               "GLY  378",
               "ARG  379",
               "GLY  380",
               "SER  381",
               "PRO  382",
               "LEU  383",
               "PRO  384",
               "PRO  385",
               "PRO  386",
               "ARG  387",
               "GLU  388",
               "ALA  389",
               "SER  390",
               "LEU  391",
               "ALA  392",
               "TRP  459",
               "HIS  460",
               "SER  461",
               "SER  462",
               "ALA    1",
               "THR    2",
               "GLN    3",
               "ALA    4",
               "ARG    5",
               "ASP    6",
               "THR    7",
               "THR  276",
               "ALA  277",
               "ILE  278",
               "GLY  279",
               "LEU  335",
               "GLY  336",
               "GLU  337",
               "GLN  338",
               "PRO  339",
               "MET  340",
               "ALA  341",
               "HIS  342",
               "ARG  343",
               "PRO  344",
               "PRO  345",
               "ALA  346",
               "THR  347",
               "PHE  348",
               "GLN  349",
               "ALA  350",
               "ASN  351",
               "LYS  352",
               "THR  353",
               "ASP  354",
               "ASP  355",
               "CYS  356",
               "SER  357",
               "ALA  358",
               "MET  359",
               "GLY  360",
               "ASN  361",
               "HIS  362",
               "CYS  363",
               "SER  364",
               "HIS  365",
               "VAL  366",
               "GLY  367",
               "GLY  368",
               "PRO  369",
               "GLN  370",
               "ASP  371",
               "LEU  372",
               "GLU  373",
               "LYS  374",
               "THR  375",
               "PRO  376",
               "ARG  377",
               "GLY  378",
               "ARG  379",
               "GLY  380",
               "SER  381",
               "PRO  382",
               "LEU  383",
               "PRO  384",
               "PRO  385",
               "PRO  386",
               "ARG  387",
               "GLU  388",
               "ALA  389",
               "SER  390",
               "LEU  391",
               "ALA  392",
               "TRP  459",
               "HIS  460",
               "SER  461",
               "SER  462",
               "ALA    1",
               "THR    2",
               "GLN    3",
               "ALA    4",
               "ARG    5",
               "ASP    6",
               "THR    7",
               "THR  276",
               "ALA  277",
               "ILE  278",
               "GLY  279",
               "LEU  335",
               "GLY  336",
               "GLU  337",
               "GLN  338",
               "PRO  339",
               "MET  340",
               "ALA  341",
               "HIS  342",
               "ARG  343",
               "PRO  344",
               "PRO  345",
               "ALA  346",
               "THR  347",
               "PHE  348",
               "GLN  349",
               "ALA  350",
               "ASN  351",
               "LYS  352",
               "THR  353",
               "ASP  354",
               "ASP  355",
               "CYS  356",
               "SER  357",
               "ALA  358",
               "MET  359",
               "GLY  360",
               "ASN  361",
               "HIS  362",
               "CYS  363",
               "SER  364",
               "HIS  365",
               "VAL  366",
               "GLY  367",
               "GLY  368",
               "PRO  369",
               "GLN  370",
               "ASP  371",
               "LEU  372",
               "GLU  373",
               "LYS  374",
               "THR  375",
               "PRO  376",
               "ARG  377",
               "GLY  378",
               "ARG  379",
               "GLY  380",
               "SER  381",
               "PRO  382",
               "LEU  383",
               "PRO  384",
               "PRO  385",
               "PRO  386",
               "ARG  387",
               "GLU  388",
               "ALA  389",
               "SER  390",
               "LEU  391",
               "ALA  392",
               "HIS  460",
               "SER  461",
               "SER  462",
               "ALA    1",
               "THR    2",
               "GLN    3",
               "ALA    4",
               "ARG    5",
               "ASP    6",
               "THR    7",
               "THR  276",
               "ALA  277",
               "ILE  278",
               "GLY  279",
               "LEU  335",
               "GLY  336",
               "GLU  337",
               "GLN  338",
               "PRO  339",
               "MET  340",
               "ALA  341",
               "HIS  342",
               "ARG  343",
               "PRO  344",
               "PRO  345",
               "ALA  346",
               "THR  347",
               "PHE  348",
               "GLN  349",
               "ALA  350",
               "ASN  351",
               "LYS  352",
               "THR  353",
               "ASP  354",
               "ASP  355",
               "CYS  356",
               "SER  357",
               "ALA  358",
               "MET  359",
               "GLY  360",
               "ASN  361",
               "HIS  362",
               "CYS  363",
               "SER  364",
               "HIS  365",
               "VAL  366",
               "GLY  367",
               "GLY  368",
               "PRO  369",
               "GLN  370",
               "ASP  371",
               "LEU  372",
               "GLU  373",
               "LYS  374",
               "THR  375",
               "PRO  376",
               "ARG  377",
               "GLY  378",
               "ARG  379",
               "GLY  380",
               "SER  381",
               "PRO  382",
               "LEU  383",
               "PRO  384",
               "PRO  385",
               "PRO  386",
               "ARG  387",
               "GLU  388",
               "ALA  389",
               "SER  390",
               "LEU  391",
               "ALA  392",
               "HIS  460",
               "SER  461",
               "SER  462",
               "ALA    1",
               "THR    2",
               "GLN    3",
               "ALA    4",
               "ARG    5",
               "ASP    6",
               "THR    7",
               "THR  276",
               "ALA  277",
               "ILE  278",
               "GLY  279",
               "LEU  335",
               "GLY  336",
               "GLU  337",
               "GLN  338",
               "PRO  339",
               "MET  340",
               "ALA  341",
               "HIS  342",
               "ARG  343",
               "PRO  344",
               "PRO  345",
               "ALA  346",
               "THR  347",
               "PHE  348",
               "GLN  349",
               "ALA  350",
               "ASN  351",
               "LYS  352",
               "THR  353",
               "ASP  354",
               "ASP  355",
               "CYS  356",
               "SER  357",
               "ALA  358",
               "MET  359",
               "GLY  360",
               "ASN  361",
               "HIS  362",
               "CYS  363",
               "SER  364",
               "HIS  365",
               "VAL  366",
               "GLY  367",
               "GLY  368",
               "PRO  369",
               "GLN  370",
               "ASP  371",
               "LEU  372",
               "GLU  373",
               "LYS  374",
               "THR  375",
               "PRO  376",
               "ARG  377",
               "GLY  378",
               "ARG  379",
               "GLY  380",
               "SER  381",
               "PRO  382",
               "LEU  383",
               "PRO  384",
               "PRO  385",
               "PRO  386",
               "ARG  387",
               "GLU  388",
               "ALA  389",
               "SER  390",
               "LEU  391",
               "ALA  392",
               "TRP  459",
               "HIS  460",
               "SER  461",
               "SER  462"      ]




code_string = "" # make string of codes then turn it into array after string is fed by loop
for i in code_and_index:

    code_indices_split = i.split()
    #print(f" the big split {acid_indices_split}")
    print()
    three_letter_code = code_indices_split[0]

    code_string += three_letter_code + " "

array_of_codes = code_string.split()




print()


dictionary_of_codes_and_indices = {}.fromkeys(array_of_codes)

print(dictionary_of_codes_and_indices)






for string in code_and_index :

    split_string = string.split()

    for code in dictionary_of_codes_and_indices.keys():

        if split_string[0] == code:

            dictionary_of_codes_and_indices[ split_string[0]] = [split_string[1] for string in dictionary_of_codes_and_indices]

print(f" dictionary, without index values assigned {dictionary_of_codes_and_indices}")
print()
for x ,y in dictionary_of_codes_and_indices.items():
    print(x,y)
```

But for some reason when I try to assign the values of the dictionary using a list comprehension, I only get 1 index that a code occurs over and over again.

```
ALA ['392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392', '392']
THR ['375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375', '375']
GLN ['370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370', '370']
ARG ['387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387', '387']
ASP ['371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371', '371']
ILE ['278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278', '278']
GLY ['380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380', '380']
LEU ['391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391', '391']
GLU ['388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388', '388']
PRO ['386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386', '386']
MET ['359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359', '359']
HIS ['460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460', '460']
PHE ['348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348', '348']
ASN ['361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361', '361']
LYS ['374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374', '374']
CYS ['363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363', '363']
SER ['462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462', '462']
VAL ['366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366', '366']
TRP ['459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459', '459']
```

I feel like I am 80% of the way there to getting what I want but I'm missing something due to my inexperience.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a look at what you have written but for now, try the code below and see if that's what you want.

```
import re

temp_dict = {}
for string in code_and_index:
    code, index = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", string).split(' ')
    try:
        temp_dict[code].append(index)
    except KeyError:
        temp_dict[code] = [index]
```

**Edited to handle duplicate values:**

```
import re

temp_dict = {}
for string in code_and_index:
    code, index = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", string).split(' ')
    try:
        if index not in temp_dict[code]:
            temp_dict[code].append(index)
    except KeyError:
        temp_dict[code] = [index]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is in this line:

```
dictionary_of_codes_and_indices[ split_string[0]] = [split_string[1] for string in dictionary_of_codes_and_indices]
```

You define a list comprehension made of the same element split_string[1] at each iteration redefining it every time. That's why you only have the last element in your final dictionary. You should happen the values to an empty list rather than using list comprehension, but what you did is a bit convoluted and even by changing that there I get some errors.

If you want, you could procede as following:

```
final_dict = {}

for c in code_and_index:

    # extract code and index
    code = c.split()[0]
    ind = c.split()[1]

    # create key in dictionary every fist time a code is seen 
    if code not in final_dict.keys():
        final_dict[code] = []

    # append index in list inside dictionary if element not yet present 
    if ind not in final_dict[code]:
        final_dict[code].append(ind)
```

Out:

```
{'ALA': ['1', '4', '277', '341', '346', '350', '358', '389', '392'],
 'THR': ['2', '7', '276', '347', '353', '375'],
 'GLN': ['3', '338', '349', '370'],
 'ARG': ['5', '343', '377', '379', '387'],
 'ASP': ['6', '354', '355', '371'],
 'ILE': ['278'],
 'GLY': ['279', '336', '360', '367', '368', '378', '380'],
 'LEU': ['335', '372', '383', '391'],
 'GLU': ['337', '373', '388'],
 'PRO': ['339', '344', '345', '369', '376', '382', '384', '385', '386'],
 'MET': ['340', '359'],
 'HIS': ['342', '362', '365', '460'],
 'PHE': ['348'],
 'ASN': ['351', '361'],
 'LYS': ['352', '374'],
 'CYS': ['356', '363'],
 'SER': ['357', '364', '381', '390', '461', '462'],
 'VAL': ['366'],
 'TRP': ['459']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
newCleanData = {}
for item in code_and_index:
    code = item[:3]
    index = item[5:]
    if code in newCleanData:
        tempList = newCleanData[code]
        tempList.append(index)
        tempList = sorted(list(set(tempList)))
        newCleanData[code] = tempList
    else:
        newCleanData[code] = [index]
#print(newCleanData)
for code, index in newCleanData.items():
    print(code, index)
```

Output:

```
ALA ['1', '4', '277', '341', '346', '350', '358', '389', '392']
THR ['2', '7', '276', '347', '353', '375']
GLN ['3', '338', '349', '370']
ARG ['5', '343', '377', '379', '387']
ASP ['6', '354', '355', '371']
ILE ['278']
GLY ['279', '336', '360', '367', '368', '378', '380']
LEU ['335', '372', '383', '391']
GLU ['337', '373', '388']
PRO ['339', '344', '345', '369', '376', '382', '384', '385', '386']
MET ['340', '359']
HIS ['342', '362', '365', '460']
PHE ['348']
ASN ['351', '361']
LYS ['352', '374']
CYS ['356', '363']
SER ['357', '364', '381', '390', '461', '462']
VAL ['366']
TRP ['459']
```

Answer (score 0):

the soultion is

```
result = {}
for token in code_and_index:
    name, value = token.split()
    result.setdefault(name, list()).append(value)

for x ,y in result.items():
    print(x,y)
```